# One of the values passed to this method or property is out of range - Range.ExportFragment issue with word 2010 vsto plugin

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, vsto, word-2010

I am trying to export a part of the document of the word to html on VSTO plugins using below method :

```
Word.Selection selectedWord = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
var tempFilename = "c://Test.html";
selectedWord.Range.ExportFragment(tempFilename, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);
```

this code is working fine in word 2013 and above but when i tried to run this code in word 2010 vsto it is giving us following exception:

```
One of the values passed to this method or property is out of range. **Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.ExportFragment(String FileName, WdSaveFormat Format)
```

at initial I thought maybe word 2010 VSTO does not support `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML` but when I tried to save the document it is showing an option to save as HTML.

Note - I also tried running word as administrator means there is no issues with directory permissions and also re-installed word.

Note - I also tried other enums of WdSaveFormat but they are also giving the same exception.

Can anyone please help.